# Incorrect Dataproc cluster substate in google client library

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to get the dataproc cluster's substate by using the google-cloud-dataproc client library. I have used the sample script from https://github.com/googleapis/python-dataproc/blob/5777e99956c24058675a8070f660835ef33c1f36/samples/snippets/list_clusters.py
After adding the lines in script to get the substate of the cluster like this

`print(("{} - {} - {}".format(cluster.cluster_name, cluster.status.state.name, cluster.status.substate.name)))`

I get the output for substate as UNSPECIFIED -

`DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://oauth2.googleapis.com:443 "POST /token HTTP/1.1" 200 None`
`<CLUSTER_NAME> - RUNNING - UNSPECIFIED`

whereas if i run a gcloud sdk command to get the substate of the cluster i get the cluster substate correctly as UNHEALTHY -

`gcloud dataproc clusters describe <CLUSTER_NAME> --region <REGION> | grep substate | tr -d ' ' | cut -f2 -d':'`
`UNHEALTHY`

I havent changed anything from the dataproc client library sample code from git but just added the code for printing substate. Here's my code -

```
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
"""Sample command-line program to list Cloud Dataproc clusters in a region.
Example usage:
python list_clusters.py --project_id=my-project-id --region=global
"""
import argparse

from google.cloud import dataproc_v1


# [START dataproc_list_clusters]
def list_clusters(dataproc, project, region):
    """List the details of clusters in the region."""
    for cluster in dataproc.list_clusters(
        request={"project_id": project, "region": region}
    ):
        print(("{} - {} - {}".format(cluster.cluster_name, cluster.status.state.name, cluster.status.substate.name)))


# [END dataproc_list_clusters]


def main(project_id, region):

    if region == "global":
        # Use the default gRPC global endpoints.
        dataproc_cluster_client = dataproc_v1.ClusterControllerClient()
    else:
        # Use a regional gRPC endpoint. See:
        # https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints
        dataproc_cluster_client = dataproc_v1.ClusterControllerClient(
            client_options={"api_endpoint": f"{region}-dataproc.googleapis.com:443"}
        )

    list_clusters(dataproc_cluster_client, project_id, region)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__, formatter_class=(argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    )
    parser.add_argument("--project_id", help="Project ID to access.", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--region", help="Region of clusters to list.", required=True)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args.project_id, args.region)
```

Please help to get the correct cluster substate using the python client library.

Comment: Curious. I suspect (!) the error is yours not Google's. You can append `--log-http` to any `gcloud` command to output the underlying HTTP requests. You can enable [Logging](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/logging.md) for the API Client Library to output the underlying HTTP requests. Perhaps compare the two? The API Client LIbraries are machine-generated stubs over the underlying APIs so -- while anything's possible -- it's unlikely that the client library is incorrect particularly as you're getting valid states (rather than errors) in the output

Comment: By the way, Python now supports a more elegant string formatting mechanism: `print(f"{cluster.cluster_name} - {cluster.status.state.name} - {cluster.status.substate.name}")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I havent changed anything from the dataproc client library sample code from git but just added the code for printing substate. I have also edited my question and added my full script. But clearly the outputs are different from 2 methods. One give unspecified and other gives unhealthy.[git code](https://github.com/googleapis/python-dataproc/blob/5777e99956c24058675a8070f660835ef33c1f36/samples/snippets/list_clusters.py)

Comment: @Bajwa Has your issue been resolved?